# PayPal OAuth 2.0 set up

Tags: spring-boot, paypal, oauth-2.0, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I refereed below video to learn how to integrate paypal with springboot.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GykDyG0ELms

According to the video no need to set up OAuth 2.0 in our development environment (Spring Boot).

but in PayPal documentation is it mentioned that "Before you can integrate a PayPal product or solution, **you must set up your development environment to get OAuth 2.0** client ID and secret credentials for the sandbox and live environments."
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

I want to clarify whether I want to set up OAuth 2.0 or not in order to smoothly using PayPal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any of PayPal's REST APIs you need the client:secret credentials to do an oauth2 request to obtain an access_token.  Then, you use this access_token in other API calls.

How to do this is documented at the page you linked: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

---

As far as integrating with springboot, I am not familiar, but you won't need to set up or install your own OAuth 2.0 service if that's what your question is asking.  Connecting to PayPal's REST APIs simply requires a connection to PayPal's /oauth2 endpoint to obtain the aforementioned access_token .  If you are using an SDK or other pre-integrated code path, this might already be implemented for you -- but if you are doing your own HTTPS calls then you need to implement the HTTPS call to /oauth2 yourself.

Comment: the video I have mentioned uses paypal sdk for integration is that the reason I do not want to setup OAuth 2.0 in my environment (spring boot)

Comment: That is two separate things. If you are using the SDK, the /oauth2 calls are implemented for you.  And regardless, there is no need to set up your own OAuth 2.0 service if that is what you are talking about. You are using an existing service -- via the SDK, in your case.